# Why my regex lets go trough special chars

Tags: jquery, validation

I guess im having a really bad brainblock right here, I'm trying to validate a username (only letters a-ZA-Z and numbers) but somehow if I write any special char it doesnt show me an error.

```
$('#user_login').blur(val_user);
$('#pass_login').blur(val_pass);

    function val_user(){
        var filter= /^[A-Za-z0-9]*/g;
        if(!filter.test($('#user_login').val())) {
            swal(
                'Ups!',
                'User not valid',
                'error'
            );
            $(this).addClass('input_error');
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('input_error');
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The expression looks good. Do you have an example for a value that does not behave as expected?

Answer (score 0):

try changing value of filter as 
var filter= /^[-\w]+$/;